# Interpreting SHAP Dependence Plot for Categorical Variables

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, game-theory, shapley-value

I'm reading about the use of Shapley values for explaining complex machine learning models and I'm confused about how I should interpret the SHAP independence plot in the case of a categorical variable.
For the plot below:

[image]

In the case of a continuous variable, the interpretation goes as follows: "... the log-odds of making over 50k increases significantly between age 20 and 40." [1](https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/plots/dependence_plot.html)

What would the interpretation for the following plot be (the plot is from the same source)?

[image]

It looks like being a working wife or a husband gives you a higher chance of earning more than 50k. But is there a formal way of stating this observation? Would saying that "the log-odds of making over 50k increases significantly when being a husband or wife," be correct?